# Script works fine in adb but not in Android code

Tags: android, shell, adb

In my code, I am trying to capture a snapshot of my android screen. And I am using a shell script for the same.

```
    proc = runtime.exec("su");
    OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
    os.write("copy".getBytes("ASCII"));
    os.flush();
    System.out.print("Finished");
```

The emulator has superuser i.e. the su file is available in the /system/xbin/ location. Here, the file copy has following content:

```
/system/bin/screencap -p /data/data/com.example.code/files/Hari123.png
```

I had compiled this file in the adb (command prompt) using:

```
adb shell chmod 6755 /system/bin/copy
```

After doing this, I executed the command in the same command prompt:

```
adb shell exec copy
```

All these works fine. However, in the Android code (mentioned in the first place), even having the following code also:

```
proc = runtime.exec("su");
```

gives a proc.exitvalue() of "1". I have been trying to fix this for a loooooon time. I have done enough search but with no use.

Can this be a problem with my emulator? Or, should I make the file "copy" native executable? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been explained many times. Even when `su` binary is available - Google does not want it to be accessible from 3rd party Java apps. By Google's design only `shell` user is allowed to escalate privileges. To be able to use `su` from your Java code you need to compile your own `su` binary without user ID check.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe the shell user is typically allowed to su, but unless they have recently changed things, on the emulator the adb shell already runs as root (rather than the shell user) anyway.  At any rate, I had missed the clues that this was likely an original 'su' binary rather than a hacked one, and if that is the case then you have the answer.

Comment: In which case, atleast the code should work fine in the device, isnt it? can you please help me understand if the script file is fine enough to be directly copied to the device sdcard? Or, should I make it binary executable or something?

Comment: The point of this answer is the suggestion that you have the wrong 'su' - that would be consistent with your report of failure even in a version of your app which doesn't try to execute the script.

Comment: Ok. So, let me try with another device. And do we get su from google itself? I tried an su from a different site.